# Prove that $\xi(G) \leq |G|-\alpha (G) +1$? Where $\xi (G)$ represents the chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory

How do you show $\xi(G) \leq |G|-\alpha (G) +1$? 
Where $\xi (G)$ represents the chromatic number and $\alpha (G)$ represents the independence number. Or provide a counterexample. I can't seem to find a counterexample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colouring the independent set in colour $1$. Let $v_1,v_2,...,v_{|G|-\alpha(G)}$ be the other vertices. Colour $v_i$ in colour $i+1$. This gives you a colouring of $G$ with $|G|-\alpha(G)+1$ so $ξ(G)\le |G|-\alpha(G)+1$

Comment: Yes but this isn't a proof

Comment: Why is it not? Is there something missing?

Comment: Is this a counterexample?

Comment: No this says that you can colour a graph in $|G|-\alpha(G)+1$ colours giving you that the chromatic number is at most that.

Comment: Yes but you need to prove it. You may not be able to colour the independence set one colour and the rest of them another. You cannot always get a chromatic number of 2

Comment: Ok I hope now it is more clear what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

A clarification: $\alpha(G)$ is the size of any largest independent set of vertices in $G$. If you are trying to assign a proper vertex coloring to $G$, then all the vertices in any independent set can get the same color. In particular, at most $\alpha(G)$ vertices can get assigned the same color. Then the remaining $|G|-\alpha(G)$ will require at most $|G|-\alpha(G)$ colors to obtain a proper vertex coloring of $G$. Thus the chromatic number of $G$ will be no more than $|G|-\alpha(G)+1$.